# Spring cloud stream not able to retrieve Array List instead String is being picked at listener

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

i am sending an Array list from Producer and i am expecting to read the same arraylist at the consumer and persist into Database.

Instead of me getting the the Object i am getting and json wrapped inside the Object,which i am not able to understand why.

Below is representation of different objects.

Expexcting:

```
user is [Users [id=1, name=Prashantrh, nm=com.example.demo.Name@2b65d9e7]]
```

Pickied up at consumer side as:

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "dmetaD":{  
            "id":2315,
            "embedded":true,
            "size":123,
            "comment":"raghu",
            "name":"string",
            "type":"pdf",
            "creationTime":"2018-05-15T20:47:48.161",
            "creatorId":15001,
            "creator":{  
               "id":15001,
               "shortId":"MARC6GR",
               "firstName":"V15001",
               "lastName":"N15001",
               "emailPref":true,
               "departmentName":"RD/FNT",
               "inventoryType":"P",
               "langPref":"DE",
               "email":"V15001.N15001@d.com"
            }
         },
         "dCont":{  
            "data":"abc"
         }
      },
      {  
         "dmetaD":{  
            "id":2316,
            "embedded":true,
            "size":123,
            "comment":"raghu",
            "name":"string",
            "type":"pdf",
            "creationTime":"2018-05-15T20:47:48.163",
            "creatorId":15001,
            "creator":{  
               "id":15001,
               "shortId":"MARC6GR",
               "firstName":"V15001",
               "lastName":"N15001",
               "emailPref":true,
               "departmentName":"RD/FNT",
               "inventoryType":"P",
               "langPref":"DE",
               "email":"V15001.N15001@d.com"
            }
         },
         "dCont":{  
            "data":"def"
         }
      }
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please provide more details as to what version of Spring Cloud Stream you are using.
That said, I am going to assume for now that you are using 2.0.0.RELEASE which means the content type of the message defaults to `application/json`.

Comment: This is 1.5.11 and yes content-type is set to application/json.

Comment: There is no Spring Cloud Stream 1.5.11. You may be referring to Spring Boot 1.5.11. In any event the the fact that you have confirmed that the content type is set to `application/json` explains the behavior. 
In any event you're probably using Spring Cloud Stream-1.3.*. You can customize message conversion using several mechanism. I would recommend to go through this section  https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR3/reference/htmlsingle/#contenttypemanagement and follow up if you still have issue. Also I would recommend to upgrade to Spring Cloud Stream 2.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: If i send single object instead of list this is getting processed but only list has a problem.

Comment: well,at any case Json shouldn't modify the data  and in here this is getting modified.Might be a bug or i am not sure.